# Sockets in Java...?

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I need to build an application which can receive data from over a network and use this data to do some unrelevant things with.

Here's a piece of code to make clear what I'm doing.

On the server side:

```
static Socket client = null;
static ServerSocket ss = null;

if (ss != null) {
                ss.close();
            }
            ss = new ServerSocket(5513);
            isrunning = true;
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            client = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted.");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```

And the client side:

```
Socket client = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
                    try {                            
                        client = new Socket("hostname", 5513);
                        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
```

Please note that this is just a piece of the code. There are no errors in the code.

After running the server-sided piece of code, it correctly waits for the client to connect.

Now here comes the problem. As soon as I try to connect from the client side, I'm getting a "connection refused"-error.

HOWEVER, I found something on the internet whoch told me to try telnetting from the client side. For example, let the server-sided IP be 192.168.1.1. So, after using this command:

```
    telnet 192.168.1.1 5513
```

I actually get a connection with the server. The command will launch an empty screen, and everything I manually type in the command line will be sent to the server-side after pressing enter (checked with debugging).

So, I can manually connect to the server-side and send some data, but my code refuses to connect.

Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why yours fails, but I got sockets running easily using these two tutorials: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/implement-simple-socket-server-in.html
and http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html

Comment: @HannahMitt, he forgot a `while` loop. The server isn't even listening for connections for more than a second. Once the server makes ONE connection, it's done and won't listen anymore.

Comment: As I said, this is just a piece of the code. I am using a while loop, actually. Besides, the accept() method will wait for a connection to establish, so I can let the server wait for hours to establish the first connection. After that, it will loop to the start for another connection.

Comment: Here's a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22079083/3315914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the code you're actually using?

```
client = new Socket("hostname", 5513);
```

Try changing it to:

```
client = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 5513);
```

Answer (score 2):

`client = new Socket("hostname", 5513);` 
Hostname needs to represent the IP Address you're connecting to. If you're trying to connect to yourself, it would be "localhost"

Also, the server is not listening for the client AT ALL TIMES, there must be a `while` loop so the server listens and accepts connections.

```
while (true) {
   client = ss.accept();
   out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
   //You should probably assign it to a seperate thread to handle stuff for this client
}
```

And I should explain on why you're getting that particular error. When something says that the connection is refused, it usually means that the IP Address you want to connect to knows your sending a connection and is blocking it because it was not listening for that connection. Basically, when the server closed, you stopped listening for the client, so anything that came in on that port would be blocked. Of course, the other case could be that Java was blocked on your firewall and an exception should be made for it. Although this is rarely the case if what you're trying to accomplish is over a LAN.

Comment: This is awkward, replacing the hostname with the IP address actually works.

Comment: Entering the hostname works for LAN connections, because I've tested that before and it does establish a connection. But for more accuracy in your connections, I would stick with IP addresses. Not to mention that method is more straightforward and direct. I would only use hostnames for website connections. The only exception is "localhost", which means "My Computer's IP Address"

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using "hostname" in your Socket object in the client are you?

It should the 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? and If so have you added java.exe and javaw.exe to Firewall with inbound and outbound enabled? and have you added a rule for 5513 to your Firewall?

If yes Windows but no Firewall settings, that's your answer, open up your Firewall.