# Socket not getting connection

Tags: java, sockets

```
public class JavaApplication15 {

    public static String ip="127.0.0.1";
    public static int port=5060;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket ss = null;
        InetAddress ii = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(ii);
        InetAddress ad = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        System.out.println(ad);

        InetAddress i = ad;
        System.out.println(i);
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
             ss = new ServerSocket();
             ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
             InetSocketAddress ia;
             String st=ss.getLocalSocketAddress().toString(); // print socket ip and address
             System.out.println(st);

             System.out.println("created");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("not created");
        }
        Socket client = null,ee = null;
        client = ss.accept();
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null ;

        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String input = null;
        while((input = in.readLine())!=null){

            System.out.println(input);
            System.out.println("echo :" +in.readLine());

        }

        out.flush();
        in.close();
        stdin.close();
        client.close();
        ss.close();

     }
}    

 }
```

---

In this code server is being created and trying to establish a connection with socket. I think this code should show output but it is not showing. For example: if i say hello in the console , it should print hello. But it is not doing that. Can anyone help me what is actually going on here ???

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be writing something to do with openSIPS or Asterisk?

Comment: What does the client code look like?

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22079083/3315914